# Unable to read data matrix barcode

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am having problem reading Data Matrix code on iPhone. I am using scanlife application. I am trying to read Data Matrix code printed from crystal reports.

Comment: Does the scanlife app support datamatrix barcodes?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: what is the size of bar code ?

Comment: Asif size of barcode is 705x705 as per crystal reports properties window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your bar code size is small on crystal report. Increase the size of bar code and then try it.